# How does R handle NA in ifelse with 2 vectors?

Tags: r, if-statement, na

Can someone please help me understand how R handles NA in ifelse statements?

Let's say I have the following vectors:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 3, NA, 4)
y <- c(1, NA, 1, NA, NA)
```

I want to create another vector based on these two vectors, and what I want the output to be is:

```
z <- c(1, 1, 2, 0, 0)
```

I have tried this:

```
z <- ifelse(x == 1, 1
            , ifelse(y == 1, 2, 0))
```

And I tried this (which seems really excessive to have to spell all of this out):

```
z <- ifelse(x == 1, 1
            , ifelse(!is.na(x)
                     , ifelse(y == 1, 2
                              , ifelse(is.na(y), 0, NA))
                     , 0))
```

In any case that didn't work either... Both of those return:

```
> z
[1]  1  1  2 NA NA
```

Can someone please help me understand not only how to get the result I want but also how R treats NA when working with ifelse involving 2 vectors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both the case add an additional check for `NA`'s since anything compared to `NA` returns `NA`.

```
ifelse(x == 1 & !is.na(x), 1, ifelse(y == 1 & !is.na(y), 2, 0))
#[1] 1 1 2 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems so obvious but also odd. I think I just need to get used it.

Answer (score 0):

We can make it compact with `%in%`

```
ifelse(x %in% 1, 1, ifelse(y %in% 1, 2, 0))
#[1] 1 1 2 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful in some instances for sure! In my actual data the x variable from my example has a lot of potential values, so using %in% in that case isn't very helpful. Either way, good to have a variety of things in my toolkit.

Comment: @beri One advantage. with `%in%` (along with the `NA` returning FALSE), it can a vector of values i.e. length `>=1`, while `==` only works with length`==1`